# Flink retry strategy - custom errors

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using the async operator to make API calls and sometimes, they fail. We would like to retry the same event again in some custom time intervals. The failure could also be because of some post-call validation, hence triggered from code. We found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11909 Not sure if this has been implemented. If not, is there a way out? Perhaps using an operator down the chain to push the events back to the async operator after a delay? Or simply push the events that need a retry back to the input stream after filtering?

Comment: This comment on Flink-11909 -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11909?focusedCommentId=16831421&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16831421 -- suggests that the user can implement their own retry logic. Haven't seen an example of that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, Flink does not support retriable asynchronous operations. The best solution at the moment is to implement the retry logic in your user code. You could take a look at [`FutureUtils.retry`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/concurrent/FutureUtils.java#L88) for an example how to do it naively.

Comment: Thanks @Till Rohrmann, I was thinking of making this external by using a window function to push the records back into the application based on time. I did not think of this!

Comment: Since we will be using `futures` , how would recovery happen in case of a failure in flink? Will these go into the state too?

Comment: If the asynchronous operation has not been completed before the failure happens, it will trigger another asynchronous operation on recovery. How you resolve potential duplicate operations wrt the external system is up to you.